# Remove proxies from Json Response Symfony2

Tags: json, symfony, serialization

I'm working in Symfony2 application and what I'm trying to do is to remove unwanted fields from response and show only fields that I want.

My JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Granit",
    "typeId": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "X or Y",
      "acroname": "xory",
      "__initializer__": null,
      "__cloner__": null,
      "__isInitialized__": true
    },
    "pushDate": {
      "timezone": {
        "name": "Europe/Berlin",
        "location": {
          "country_code": "DE",
          "latitude": 52.5,
          "longitude": 13.36666,
          "comments": "most locations"
        }
      },
      "offset": 7200,
      "timestamp": 1460584800
    },
    "addedAt": {
      "timezone": {
        "name": "Europe/Berlin",
        "location": {
          "country_code": "DE",
          "latitude": 52.5,
          "longitude": 13.36666,
          "comments": "most locations"
        }
      },
      "offset": 7200,
      "timestamp": 1460548644
    },
    "deviceToShow": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Mobile",
      "__initializer__": null,
      "__cloner__": null,
      "__isInitialized__": true
    },
    "statusSurvey": false,
    "slides": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "First Question",
        "picture1": "160413015724bazinga2.jpg",
        "picture2": "160413015724th.jpg",
        "idSurvey": 1,
        "absolutePathpic1": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\stu-wrapper\\src\\AppBundle\\Entity/../../../web/uploads/slideSurvey/160413015724bazinga2.jpg",
        "webPathpic1": "uploads/slideSurvey/160413015724bazinga2.jpg",
        "absolutePathpic2": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\stu-wrapper\\src\\AppBundle\\Entity/../../../web/uploads/slideSurvey/160413015724th.jpg",
        "webPathpic2": "uploads/slideSurvey/160413015724th.jpg",
        "file": null,
        "file1": null
      }
    ],
    "categories": []
  }
]
```

I want to remove fields like  "**initializer**": null,"**cloner**": null, "**isInitialized**": true and hide timezone object and show only "timestamp".

Here is my controller where I'm doing serializing and creating Json Response.

```
public function getAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine ()->getManager ();
        $survey = $em->getRepository ( 'AppBundle:Survey' )->findAll ();

        if ( !$survey ) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException ( 'Data not found.' );
        }
        $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
        $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
        $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler ( function ( $survey ) {
            return $survey->getid ();
        } );


        $serializer = new Serializer( array ( $normalizer ), array ( $encoder ) );

        $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize ( $survey, 'json' );

        return new Response( $jsonContent );
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: So, the Doctrine2 create a proxy classes for lazy loads all relations. And you can full configure this operation. You must a create custom serializer/encoder/converter for convert you entity to another data (xml/json).

Answer (score 2):

Try to exclude this fields:

```
$normalilzer->setIgnoredAttributes(
    [
        "__initializer__", 
        "__cloner__",
        "__isInitialized__"
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Detach entity to remove doctrine2 links to the object

```
$em->detach($survey);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I only used JMSSerializerBundle and it handled this problem.